# How do you roll for an Animal Companion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class, animal-companions

I am about to start a *Pathfinder* campaign as a [Cavalier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier]) for the first time, and I've hit a bit of a quandary. As dictated by [Animal Companions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions), my mount should have one hit die. However, when looking at a [boar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/boar/boar) (my guy is a gnome), the animal has a roll of 2D8+9. Considering Toughness and the boar's +3 CON modifier, does this mean that my boar has 2D8 per hit die (around 18HP), a single D8 per hit die (around 10HP)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a cavalier to select a boar, he must be at least 4th level. At 4th level, an animal companion has 4 HD, not 1 (in fact, even at 1st, animal companions still have 2 HD).

The boar, meanwhile, has 2 HD to begin with. Each one is a d8 (**all** animals use d8 hit dice, and there is no such thing as a “hit die” that consists of multiple dice), so 2d8 total. Monster entries always list HD this way.

Your boar, having 4 HD, will be 4d8 instead of 2d8, plus 4×Con, plus 4 for Toughness. On average, that will be 34 HP.